# ST_ClusterDBSCAN in Bigquery, how to get a list of points for each cluster?

Tags: clustering

The algorithm DBSCAN should be able to group points together in clusters based on their proximity.

However, the example in GCB Bigquery has only the number of clusters.

```
WITH Geos as
  (SELECT 1 as row_id, st_geogfromtext('point empty') as geo UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, st_geogfromtext('multipoint(1 1, 2 2, 4 4, 5 2)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, st_geogfromtext('point(14 15)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, st_geogfromtext('linestring(40 1, 42 34, 44 39)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, st_geogfromtext('polygon((40 2, 40 1, 41 2, 40 2))'))
SELECT row_id, geo, ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(geo, 1e5, 1) OVER () AS cluster_num FROM
Geos ORDER BY row_id
+--------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| row_id |                geo                | cluster_num |
+--------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
|      1 |          GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY |        NULL |
|      2 |    MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 5 2, 4 4) |           0 |
|      3 |                      POINT(14 15) |           1 |
|      4 |    LINESTRING(40 1, 42 34, 44 39) |           2 |
|      5 | POLYGON((40 2, 40 1, 41 2, 40 2)) |           2 |
+--------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
```

Is there any way to get a list of points for each individual cluster?
I'm not that familiar with the OVER() notation.

Comment: list of points, do you mean id's or geometries?

Comment: @TimothyDalton yes, each geometry is a geolocation point. I need to have a list with the points assigned to each cluster-id discover by DBSCAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` the result by cluster_num, e.g.

```
WITH Geos as
  (SELECT 1 as row_id, st_geogfromtext('point empty') as geo UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, st_geogfromtext('multipoint(1 1, 2 2, 4 4, 5 2)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, st_geogfromtext('point(14 15)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, st_geogfromtext('linestring(40 1, 42 34, 44 39)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, st_geogfromtext('polygon((40 2, 40 1, 41 2, 40 2))')),
Clusters as 
  (SELECT row_id, geo, ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(geo, 1e5, 1) OVER () AS cluster_num 
    FROM Geos)
SELECT cluster_num, ARRAY_AGG(row_id) as rowids, ST_Union_Agg(geo) as geo
FROM Clusters GROUP BY cluster_num
```

Gives you

```
Row cluster_num rowids  geo 
1   null        [1]     GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
2   0           [2]     MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 5 2, 4 4)
3   1           [3]     POINT(14 15)
4   2           [4,5]   GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(40.0531529143594 2.00001531864666, 42 34, 44 39), POLYGON((40 2, 40 1, 41 2, 40.0531529143594 2.00001531864666, 40 2)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I find this solution a few days ago, it is exactly the same.